# Recommended color range for background color

Tags: color, color-scheme, color-perception, background

I am building an online menu for restaurants.

The default background color is a light gray (`#f1f3f5`). The default text color is black (`#555555`). [Example](https://buonmenu.com/example)

Many of the restaurants have asked to use a custom color for the background. At first I said no, because users are not designers and use colors awfully... but after many requests I am starting to investigate a solution.

**The idea is to allow the user to pick any color. Then the color is adjusted within a range.**

In particular we would like to keep **a light background with dark text on it**.

So the solution was to use **HSL** and force **L** to a **minimum of `0.9`**.

It has a sufficient effect, but I am not 100% satisfied.

**Is there any study about the acceptable color range for a full-screen background (*saturation*, *luminance*)?**

Comment: After further investigation I have found that Chrome desktop itself, for the customizable Google home / Chrome theme, adjusts the color inserted by the user. In particular, for light background (luminance > 70%), it move the lightness to about 90% (not always the same). So I am correct. I have also noticed that it changes the saturation... **I would be curious to know what exact formula Chrome is using**.

Comment: Why don't you just provide a set of colours that you think are acceptable and the user can pick from those. Like 10 different colours for example, and build the UI to promote selection of one of those set colours. Then also, hidden away somewhere, there is an option to set any colour they want. End of the day, if the user wants a bright red background then that's their choice to make.

Comment: If restaurants want the background color to match the identity color of the restaurant, it won't be easy to satisfy them with an automatically adjusted color.

Answer (score 6):

Acceptable can be defined as something that is accessible to users. [WCAG 2.1 / 1.4.3 Contrast (Minimum)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/quickref/?currentsidebar=%23col_overview#contrast-minimum) requires contrast ratio between text and background to be 4.5:1 or more. From [Understanding Success Criterion 1.4.3: Contrast (Minimum)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/contrast-minimum.html) we see that contrast ratio is calculated as:

> (L1 + 0.05) / (L2 + 0.05),
>
> where
>
> - L1 is the relative luminance of the lighter of the colors, and
> - L2 is the relative luminance of the darker of the colors.

Relative luminance of your chosen text color (#555555) is [0.09084171118340767](https://contrast-ratio.com/#%23555-on-%23fff). Minimum contrast ratio is 4.5:1, so our calculation now looks like

> (L1 + 0.05) / (0.09084171118340767 + 0.05) >= 4.5

With little math magic we get

> L1 >= 0.583788

So from the accessibility point of view acceptable background color has a relative luminance between 0.583788 and 1.

Comment: Thank you very much! What is exactly `luminance`? How can I compute that? I thought that I could simply use the L from HSL, but for `#555555` I get 0.33 and not 0.09 as you said...

Comment: Ok found this: https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Relative_luminance So they call luminance different things...

Comment: I don't know how luminance is calculated. I just used values from this color contrast calculator https://contrast-ratio.com/ and just thought they are correct as it calculates contrast the way mentioned in WCAG. :D